# JQuery Ajax File Upload Content-Type always false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file, upload

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'localhost/test',
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                data: formdata,
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
```

But the header request content type is not right, it returns false either.

[image]

I think it should looks like this

[image]

Comment: you have forced `contentType: false` in you ajax request

Comment: yes, i give it contentType false but the request header is false either, please see the attachment image

Comment: what are you returning from test page?

Comment: i did some research on google, they say set contentType to false so that the content type will be multipart/form-data. But in my case, this doesn't work.

Comment: your jquery version?